# Shaders in Cocos2d 2.0

Tags: cocos2d

I'm thinking of using cocos2d 2.0 for my next project and am wanting to know if it's possible to have a shader that renders to a texture and that texture be input into another shader?

I have a few effects that need this capability, but haven't been able to find anything that says you can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CCRenderTexture for this purpose..

http://www.raywenderlich.com/3857/how-to-create-dynamic-textures-with-ccrendertexture

in the draw code, you can always use: texture.sprite.shaderProgram ...